# Bootstrap 4 max height div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a 2 column layout, where the first column will be a vertical nav, and the right column will be for the content.

I'd like to first column to be at least 100% of the viewport size, but it needs to grow if the main content is greater than the view port.

How do I get the first (yellow) column to be the same height as the second column?

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}

#yellow {
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-3 h-100" id="yellow">
      XXXX
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 h-100">
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sounds like you need to set `min-height` not `height`, so the _first column will be at least 100%_ - a minimum of 100%

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Bootstrap 4 uses flexbox the columns are equal height, but the `h-100` you're using is limiting the height when the content is taller than the viewport.

**Simply use the `min-vh-100` class on the yellow div.**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 min-vh-100" id="yellow">
      XXXX
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/K7T1fXEl5p

You **don't need the extra CSS** for height on the `html,body` or yellow div. This will also work when there is less content (shorter that viewport height): https://www.codeply.com/go/xdkXsLWRJt

Answer (score 2):

Use flexbox for this.

```css
.row {
  display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.col {
  flex: 1; /* additionally, equal width */
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
}
.bg-yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col bg-yellow">
    XXXX
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
      Content goes here<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The Bootstrap `.row` is `display:flex`, but when there is very little content this will not fill the viewport height.

Comment: @Zim Put on the class .row min-height: 100vh; But he already had that?

Comment: I don't see that he had min-height.